# Typedef struct causes program to crash

Tags: c, function, struct, queue, typedef

I'm trying to enqueue a struct array but it crashes whenever I try to insert information into it.

The struct itself looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char first_name;
    char last_name;
    char pers_nbr;
} person;
```

While the function looks like this:

```
void enqueue(person pers)
{
    strcpy(queue[tail].first_name, pers.first_name);
    strcpy(queue[tail].last_name, pers.last_name);
    strcpy(queue[tail].pers_nbr, pers.pers_nbr);

    tail = (tail+1) % QUEUE_MAX_SIZE;
    nbr_elem++;
}
```

I've been debugging and it crashes at the first strcpy and returns the error "Access violation reading location". The issue seems to be with the pers object.

Here's how I've been trying to insert data:

```
person test;
test.first_name = "John";
test.last_name = "Doe";
test.pers_nbr = "A";
enqueue(test);
```

What causes this crash and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Consider compiling with all warnings on, fix the code until no more warnings appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a variable like

```
char first_name;
```

it means there is space for one character

you should instead use an array of characters to hold the string

```
char first_name[64];
```

and

```
person test;
test.first_name = "John";
```

is not the correct way to initialize a string or a struct, either do it in the declaration or manually strcpy in the string as u did previously:

```
person test = { "John", "Doe", "A" };
```

Comment: That makes sense, I tried going with an array of characters at first too but it started spitting out errors when I used "test.first_name = "John";" but after trying your way to initialize the struct it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The char types in the struct should be char* in order to store strings, otherwise they just store a single character. Furthermore, space should be allocated for them.